# How to tell slurm to cache config file for multiple submissions

Tags: python, config, slurm, sbatch

I have three scripts:

`config.yaml` and `script.py` and `slurm.sh`

I am submitting job to the job scheduler in `Slurm` using the `slurm.sh` file which calls the `script.py` file and the `script.py` files loads the config from the `config.yaml` file.

It would look like this:

`sbatch slurm.sh`

Now, I change the `config.yaml` and submit another job. However, if both jobs are in the queue, the `config.yaml` file will be overwritten and both jobs will use the same configuration.

Is there any way to tell the `slurm` scheduler to cache the `config.yaml` file as well? I know it is dont for the `slurm.sh` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to achieve that. You should modify your script (.sh) to point to the proper configuration file before submission, and create as many configuration files as needed.

Another option could be to convert the configuration file entries to command line parameters (if possible) before submission and submit a script with a fully configured command line (so no need to read the .yaml file).

Comment: That is a pity. But I guess I have to live with that.

Comment: Just learned today about the `--wrap` option to sbatch. It could be useful for your scenario, but you would have to extract the yaml configuration and pass it to the script via command line.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!